# Mixing microProfile-5.0 and Jakarta EE 9.1 messaging features in Liberty

Tags: open-liberty

Migrating server from microProfile-4.1 to microProfile-5.0 and based on  https://openliberty.io/blog/2021/11/26/jakarta-ee-9.1.html, I map wasJmsClient-2.0 to messagingClient-3.0 and wasJmsServer-1.0 to messagingServer-3.0.

```
    <featureManager>
        <feature>microprofile-5.0</feature>
        <feature>messagingServer-3.0</feature>
        <feature>messagingClient-3.0</feature>      
    </featureManager>
```

The server seems not able to start reporting some conflicting versions of features.
From what I understand all are Jakarta EE 9.1 compatible but if not what are the best option to replace wasJmsClient-2.0 and wasJmsServer-1.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this should work. I am not sure how you are installing liberty and the features which could make a difference.  There were some issues with installing of features not including all dependent features earlier this year.   So I would ask that you include what version of liberty you are using and how you installed it and possibly how you installed the features.  I just tried with the latest code and it started up cleanly for me.  So if you can also provide details about what the error message looks like that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it should work. Started from a 22.0.0.7 kernel and extending needed features on demand from microprofile 4 to 5. Launched all that in eclipse.
Will test again with a fresh reinstall.

Comment: How are you installing the features?  featureManager, liberty maven plugin, liberty gradle plugin?  If you are using one of the plugins, you may want to move up to a newer version because several fixes were put in that may have resolved the problem you are seeing.